# What exact formula should i use to calculate the hydrostatic force in this wrong?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, physics

what am i supposed to do? If you please explain to me step by step. I'm lost after long time trying and my answer is always being different.

> Q: A vertical dam has the form of an isosceles trapezoid with horizontal sides parallel.  The dam is 30 m high, 20 m in its lower part and 40 m in its upper part. Finally, the dam retains 25 m of water, as indicated in the ﬁgure below.
>
> [image: img]
>
> a) Let $y$ denote the height in meters measured from the base of the dam. The hydrostatic force exerted by the water on the portion of the door comprised between $y$ m and $y+\Delta y$ m is approximately $p(y)\Delta y$  N.
>
> What is $p(y)$? Note that the density of water is $\rho=1000$  Kg/m$^3$ and the acceleration due to gravity on the earth’s surface is $g=9.8$  m/s$^2$. Express your answer as a formula.
>
> b) In Newtons, what is the total hydrostatic force exerted on the dam?
> Give the answer correct to 3 signiﬁcant digits.

Comment: sorry for that. is it unclear?

Comment: now? is it good?

Comment: Not saying that's a big deal, but not giving any feedback about an answer seems kind of ungrateful

Answer (score 1):

The hydrostatic force is the product of water pressure and surface, i.e.
$$F=P\times S$$
Now between $y$ and $y+\Delta y$ the portion of surface is:
$$\Delta S=w(y)\Delta y$$
where $w(y)$ is the width of dam at $y$:
$$\frac{w-20}{w_{max}-20}=\frac y{y_{max}}\implies w(y)=20+20\frac y{30}=20+\frac 23 y$$
and
$$P=\rho gh=9800(30-y)$$
So just write:
$$dF=P\,dS=p(y)dy=9800(30-y)(20+2y/3)dy$$
Now with $p(y)=9800(30-y)(20+2y/3)$ you can do the rest:
$$F=\int dF=\int_0^{30} p(y)dy=(5880000 y- \frac{19600}9 y^3)|_0^{30}=1.176\times 10^8$$